On Linux, how to allow send/receive multicast between applications?
I have a question regarding sending/receiving multicast traffic between 2 applications on the same system.
The multicast address I am asking particularly is 802.1X EAPOL traffic (01:80:c2:00:00:03)
Basically, I have a hostapd running on my ethernet interface (eth0) that listen for 802.1X request as authenticator, while I run wpa_supplicant that act as supplicant that uses PEAP.
However, if both run on the same system, the hostapd acted as it never receive the request, but through tcpdump, the EAPOL start does detected on the ethernet interface.
I think the problem lies where program that listen on multicast address will not receive its multicast traffic within its system.  I try bind wpa_supplicant or hostapd on other etherent interface, but still won't work.  Is there a way to setup multicast communication between 2 programs?

Are you coding the applications? If not, this isn't a programming question.

Well....I am thinking coding radius client myself for handling eap (at least peap) coming from wpa_supplicant, replacing hostapd.  But before that, I need to know how to get multicast traffic sending from its own system, in order to perform subsequent radius request.
